# The same UIView in two places at once?

Tags: user-interface, cocoa-touch, uikit

In order to explain what problem I am having I will quickly explain the scenario.  I have a synthesizer I am building that has several "control views".  One control view may be 4 vertical sliders while another is one big matrix or something..  So, say I have control views 1-4.  In addition, I have two main sections (which are just holder views), which can contain one of the 4 control views.  At any given moment, `sectionA` can have `controlView4` while `sectionB` can have `controlView2`.  This works perfectly.

The problem with this is `SectionA` cannot have `ControlView1` while `SectionB` has `ControlView1` simultaneously.  This leads to undesirable behavior.  For example, if `SectionA` currently has `ControlView1` while `SectionB` has `ControlView4` (which will wrap around to `ControlView1` on the next toggle), than the next time I toggle `SectionB`'s active ControlView, `SectionA`'s ControlView will simply disappear.  (presumably because UIKit implicitly removes it from `SectionA`'s subviews when I add it as a `SectionB`'s subview.)

So, there is some default behavior of UIView that isn't ideal for this modular scheme I wish to implement.  That being said, is there a way to achieve what I want without deviating to far afield from iOS best practices and sane code design?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would want to have a different type of view controller for each type of view.  Then, each time I wanted a view in a section, I would create its matching controller and have it take over that container area.  If the four sections are then displaying multiple copies of the same view, they each have their own controller to keep them organized.

Assuming you have your data model separate from your views and controllers, there should be no extra complexity.

Comment: thanks.  the key take away i got from that is i need more model abstraction in my architecture to even begin to think about doing what i want.  The key parts i think are a tabBarVC to select between various VC's such as a MatrixVC a 4SlidersVC, each having a view and model to store state finally with the models interacting with state of the synthesizer audio engine.  although that last step is not clear yet.

Comment: Sounds good.  With the flexibility you describe, the last thing you want is a need to pass state from controller to controller.